# File transfer using IICS

Tags: file-transfer, informatica, iics, iics-mi

I have a requirement where I need to transfer 1000s of files(around 200 GB) via IICS. How can I perform this using IICS?

The files are stored in a server that does not run a secure agent which makes it complicated

Comment: Hi - why do you need to use IICS to move files? If you can’t install a secure agent on a system that has access to the files, what mechanism are you planning to use that can access these files?

Comment: This is more of a “is it possible with IICS” kind of question. The server is owned by a vendor.

Comment: Hi - yes it is possible, by the vendor installing a secure agent on the server. If you can’t tell us how the vendor will allow access to these files then this question is basically unanswerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible, the module to be used exactly for this purpose is [Mass Ingestion](https://docs.informatica.com/data-engineering/data-engineering-integration/10-2-1/mass-ingestion-guide/introduction-to-mass-ingestion/overview.html). This is not a scenario for CDI.

You don't need a Secure Agent on either source or target server. What you need instead, is the connections on the Secure Agent to the source and target servers, then you define the job - and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SFTP,share the keys which is a one time activity. Any from,the Unix team can do ,once it's done you can create the connection in IICS admin console. After that,use mass ingestion thru IICS to pull the files.

HTH.

Regards,
Tech_Seeker